# Access Office for multi OS

Tags: angular, microsoft-access

We would need advice on 1 project that we want to achieve

Currently we create BDD under Access (microsoft office), but some customers want to use the database on Mac or smartphone, the problem is that Access does not exist on Mac, smartphone side it is problem too.

So we are looking for a simple way to run our databases on as many systems as possible (windows, android, ios ...).

For example we create databases that can manage quotes and invoices under Access, the constraint is that the client must have Access and be on Windows.

The ideal would be to create a webapp with Cordova / Ionic, so the application would be accessible online (there will be no need for software to install) with the ability to edit files or transfer via Filezilla as a website.

Knowing that we have good knowledge in html / css, would the use of Ionic or Cordova be a good solution for our project?

Thank you

Have a good day

Comment: That is two questions.  Please ask them separately so that they can receive clear answers.

Comment: Hi, i have separately the question.
Thanks